# How to use heredoc to create a yaml file in k8s pod yaml definition?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, heredoc

I would like to create a yaml once the k8s pod is up, in my previous attempt, I just upload the yaml file and use wget to download it.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: p-test
      image: p-test:latest
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          wgethttps://ppt.cc/aId -O labels.yml
      image: test/alpine-utils
```

In order to make it more explicit, I try to use heredoc to embed the content of `labels.yml` into the k8s pod manifest, like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: p-test
      image: p-test:latest
      command:
        - "/bin/bash"
        - '-c'
        - > 
          cat << LABEL > labels.yml

          key: value

          LABEL
```

But it doesn't work, please suggest how to modify it, thanks.

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not a problem description. Please describe the observed behavior and how it differs from what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of playing with `heredoc` in pod definition, it's much better and convenient to define your `yaml` file in [the ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and refer to it in your pod definition (mount it as volume and [use `subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)) - like in this example (I changed `p-test` image into `nginx` image):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  labels.yaml: |-
    key: value
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: p-test
      image: nginx:latest
      volumeMounts:
      - name: my-configmap-volume
        mountPath: /tmp/labels.yaml
        subPath: labels.yaml
  volumes:
  - name: my-configmap-volume
    configMap:
      name: my-configmap
```

Then on the pod you will find your `labels.yaml` in the `/tmp/labels.yaml`.

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, we finally use configMap.